# SimpleSaml Memcache Username/Password

Tags: simplesamlphp

After looking at the documentation, I can't figure out how to set the memchached username and password for a memcache_store server. Does anybody know?

https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-maintenance#section_2

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 'store.type' => 'sql', then add:

```
'store.sql.dsn' => 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME,
'store.sql.username' => DB_USER,
'store.sql.password' => DB_PASSWORD,
```

to /saml/config/config.php